# LA Sound Group June '12

Tags: social, networking, learning, meet-up

For all you LA SSD'ers (or those visiting town), the LA Sound Group is having a meeting on Thursday 6/28 with guest speaker Ann Scibelli. You may recognize her from [her appearances on designingsound.org and soundworkscollection.com](http://designingsound.org/tag/ann-scibelli/), or just from her [awesome body of work](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0778439/).

If you're going to be near Santa Monica with nothing to do Thursday night, now you've got something to put on your calendar. RSVP [here](http://lasoundgroup.com), otherwise '[Like Us' on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/pages/LA-Sound-Group/201592673251316) to get the notifications of future meetings.